# Parse Server returning "{"code":111,"error":"This is not a valid File"}" for PUT but not GET. Why?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I am working my way through a migration from Parse.com to Parse Server and am not able to update any data. GET works just fine without modifying any existing code that was working with Parse.com previously.

I get a variant of this for any PUT:

```
{
    method:"PUT"
    path:"/parse/classes/Order/WzxHamIlOq"
    status:400
    text:"{"code":111,"error":"This is not a valid File"}"
}
```

A GET to `/parse/classes/Order/WzxHamIlOq` works perfectly.

I've looked up the 111 code and the only thing in the documentation that references it doesn't appear to apply.

Here is the code that DOES NOT work:

```
    OrderController.updateOrder = function(req, res) {
        var order = req.body;
        superagent
            .put(config.API_URL + '/classes/Order/' + order.objectId)
            .set('X-Parse-Application-Id', config.keys.appId)
            .set('X-Parse-Master-Key', config.keys.master)
            .send({
                'orderNo': order.orderNo,
                'poNO': order.poNO,
                'invoiceNo': order.invoiceNo,
                'dueDate': order.dueDate,
                'dateIn': order.dateIn,
                'jobName': order.jobName,
                'notes': order.notes,
                'salesmanID': {
                    __type: 'Pointer',
                    className: 'Salesman',
                    objectId: order.salesmanID.objectId
                },
                'costReview': order.costReview,
                'inProduction': order.inProduction,
                'invoice': order.invoice,
                'paid': order.paid,
                'commission': order.commission,
                'productionNotes': order.productionNotes,
                'proof': {
                    __type: 'File',
                    name: order.proof.name
                },
                'tags': order.tags,
                'artUrl': order.artUrl
            })
            .end(function(err, results){
                if(err) {
                    res.status(500).send({error: err});
                }else if(results.badRequest){
                        console.error(results.error);
                        res.status(results.status).send({error: results.error});

                }else {
                    res.send(results.body);
                }
            });
    };
```

Here is the GET to the same path that DOES work:

```
    OrderController.getOrderInfo = function(req, res) {
        superagent
            .get(config.API_URL + '/classes/Order/' + req.params.id)
            .set('X-Parse-Application-Id', config.keys.appId)
            .set('X-Parse-Master-Key', config.keys.master)
            .query('include=salesmanID,imprintTypeID,customerID')
            .query('where')
            .end(function(err, results) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else if(results.badRequest){
                    console.error(results.error);
                    res.status(results.status).send({error: results.error});

                }else {
                    res.send(results.body);
                }
            });
    };
```

Yes, using Super Agent instead of the sdk is stupid. Yes, I did inherit this code.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: I think the problem would be when you are trying to save file in the row, I would try removing all lines you are trying to save and trying to figure out which one is returning the error... or maybe you have to use Master Key cause of permissions? Is the file bigger than 20 MB?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Am able to get a save with just a single property. Will work from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the Parse db migration tool has no support for transferring files out of Parse.

There is an active issue on github, but no official solution yet: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/8

These lines are what cause the issue:

```
'proof': {
    __type: 'File',
    name: order.proof.name
},
```